# Optimize Efficiency of copying content from many csv files and transpose pasting them into a master Excel file with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a directory containing tens of thousands of csv files (that used to be HTML files but I wrote a different vba script that changed the extension to csv), that I want placed into one Main xls file (called Main Import File VBA). Given the huge number of csv files that I need to loop over, I want to do it as efficiently as possible (lowest amount of time necessary. If I can get my code a few percentages faster, that would already make a huge difference.

The csv files are all similar. Basically HTML files that now have a csv extension. All the data is in one column (although length of rows can differ). So I need to perform a similar task in that I only need to copy column A from every csv file.

I have written a code that opens each csv file and copies the content of column A and then (transpose) pastes it into the main import file (myMasterFile). It then closes the csv file and loops to the next file.

```
Sub PutInMasterFile()
    
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim myMasterFile As String
    Dim masterWB    As Workbook
    Dim rowNum      As Integer
    Dim copyRange   As Range
    Dim pasteRange  As Range
    Dim myPath      As String
    Dim myFile      As String
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim x           As Variant
    Dim C           As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    
    x = 2
    myMasterFile = "C:\S_A\VBA Test\Main Import File VBA.xlsm"
    'Workbooks("Main Import File VBA").Activate
    
    Set pasteRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & x)
    
    myPath = "C:\S_A\VBA Test\Output\"
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.csv")
    
    Start = Timer
    Do While myFile <> vbNullString
        
        'csv file opened here
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile
        
        'selection made for copying the data
        With Workbooks(myFile).Sheets(1)
            
            Range("A1").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
                                    False, Transpose:=True
            
            'Close the csv file
            Workbooks(myFile).Close
            myFile = Dir()
            
            x = x + 1
            Set pasteRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & x)
            
        End With
    Loop
    
    Finish = Timer
    TotalTime = Finish - Start
    
    MsgBox "Total time is " & TotalTime & " seconds!"
    
End Sub
```

How can I optimize this script? I think using Select and Copy (for the csv files) is inefficient, but I'm not sure I can use the optimized manner since I want to transpose paste it into myMasterFile.

Also I wonder whether it's really necessary to open (and close) each csv file. Is there a way to avoid this and get the content using a better manner?

**EDIT**:
Response to the remarks/questions from Taller and Tim Williams. I have tested the code for 25 csv files. It takes about 9.8 seconds to finish. When I leave out the copy/transpose paste part it takes about 6.5 seconds. So I guess considerably faster. I should make a change there right? (avoiding Select and Selection Copy).

As for how the csv files looks: hope this helps (it's about 1600 rows long (but it can differ per file).
I have no experience with Powerquery/Parsing HTML, or the suggestion that you posted @Tim Williams (array flipping)

[image]

Comment: Please show sample file (csv) in your post. HTML files usually have many tags. It's different with csv.

Comment: How long does it take currently?  If you comment out the copy/paste code (ie. just open/close each file) then how does the timing change?

Comment: Copying the values to an array, flipping them into another array and then putting that array on the worksheet is about 40x faster than Copy/PasteSpecial/Transpose

Comment: ...tested using a single column of 50 values

Comment: Renaming a file doesn't change the content. If you write *Mercedes* on a *Volkswagen* it's still a *Mercedes*...

Comment: It takes about just less than a second to open and close an HTML file (containing a single <table>) in Excel.  If you can share a sample file as requested by taller, there may be suggestions for faster approaches.

Comment: I may have misunderstood exactly what it is you're trying to do here - I was assuming you're trying to extract some tabular information from those files, but now looking at your screenshot I have no idea...

Comment: @TimWilliams Correct. I am trying to extract tabular information, but I'm probably doing it in a very inefficient manner. When I run the script to change the extension (from html to csv) this is how the csv files look like. I then want to copy column A and transpose paste it as a row in the main file (and do this for all tens of thousands of csv files). Then I write the data to another file to align the column values. I do this last part because the columns values can be at different locations. So for example Intance ID (row 22 and 23) can be at another row in a different csv file.

Comment: Yes that sounds like long way around to do something similar to what I posted.  You could open and read the html files directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested if VBA is faster then just plain powerquery

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\temp12"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Extension] = ".csv"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "data", each Table.Transpose(Table.SelectColumns(Csv.Document([Content]),"Column1"))),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Name","data"}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Removed Other Columns", "data"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
#"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "data",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand )
in #"Expanded"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the HTML is faster than opening the files in Excel.

Approx 12sec for 100 files.

```
Sub TestExtract()
    Const DATA_DIR As String = "C:\Temp\HTML data\"
    Dim doc As Object, tables As Object, table As Object, rows As Object
    Dim r As Long, wb As Workbook, i As Long, t, arr, f
    
    Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    t = Timer
    f = Dir(DATA_DIR & "data*.html")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        i = i + 1
        'Debug.Print f
        doc.Body.innerhtml = GetContent(DATA_DIR & f)
        Set tables = doc.Body.getElementsByTagName("table")
        If tables.Length > 0 Then
            Set rows = tables(0).getElementsByTagName("tr") 'get rows from first table
            ReDim arr(rows.Length - 1) 'size array for output
            For r = 1 To rows.Length   'get value from first cell in row
                arr(r - 1) = rows(r - 1).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
            Next r
        End If
        'put the data in a row on the worksheet
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    
    Debug.Print "Done", Timer - t
End Sub

Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  OpenTextFile(f, 1).ReadAll()
End Function
```

Comment: I tried to use this Parsing function, but it gives me Run-Time Error 424 (Object required) at the line 
"Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr"

After I add another worksheet (called Sheet1) and I refer to that sheet instead of my initial sheet, it no longer gives an error, but it runs without doing anything. When I debug it, everything seems to work more or less, but still the sheets are empty. It recognizes the HTML files in the directory, and goes through all the loops, but it doesn't fill arr.
arr(r-1)=<Subscript out of range> or it is ""

Comment: I can take a look but I'd need a sample file to work with.  Are you able to share one?  Either here or via email.

Comment: Yes I can share via mail preferably. How can I send you a private message without my mail being visible. Thank you!

Comment: Thank You. You can delete. I will send a few HTML files. If so you can see the issues.

Comment: OK I will be able to look at it tomorrow maybe.  Let me know when you send the files which parts you're interested in extracting.